# How to disable or enable TCP window scaling (RFC 1323) in NS2

Tags: networking, tcp, tcl, ns2

I'm using NS2 for simulating a network and studying the effect of RFC 1323 in TCP.
I created 3 nodes, one TCP Agent and TCPSink agent . Created One FTP source and attached with node0. But I am unable to figure out how to disable or enable window scaling option. I tried 
 `$sink set ts_echo_rfc1323_ false`  but it does not make any differences. How can I disable and enable rfc1323 in NS2.

Please take a look at the code that I used. I am new to NS2 , so what I am missing here?

```
global s
set s [new Simulator]

set nam_trace [open b.nam w]
set all_trace [open b.trace w]
$s trace-all $all_trace
$s namtrace-all $nam_trace

proc finish {} {
    global s nam_trace all_trace
    $s flush-trace
    close $nam_trace
    close $all_trace
    exit 0
} 

 set n0 [$s node]
 set n1 [$s node]
 set n2 [$s node]
 set n3 [$s node]


$s duplex-link $n0 $n1 100Mb 60ms DropTail 
$s duplex-link $n1 $n2 100Mb 60ms DropTail 
$s duplex-link $n2 $n3 100Mb 60ms DropTail

$s duplex-link-op $n0 $n1 orient right-up
$s duplex-link-op $n2 $n3 orient right

set tcp [new Agent/TCP]
$tcp set timestamps_ true
$tcp set window_ 1000000
$s attach-agent $n0 $tcp

set sink [new Agent/TCPSink/Sack1]
$sink set ts_echo_rfc1323_ true
$s attach-agent $n3 $sink

$s connect $tcp $sink

set ftp [new Application/FTP]

$ftp attach-agent $tcp
$ftp set type_ FTP

$s at 0 "$ftp start"
$s at 30 "$ftp stop"

$s at 31 "finish"

$s run
```

Comment: Post some code. In general window scaling is only enabled if needed, which only happens if the socket already has a receive buffer > 64k before it is connected or accepted.

Comment: @EJP I added my code .

Comment: You need to enable a large receive window at the *receiver.*

Comment: @EJP Could you please tell me how it can be done?

Comment: Well your client here is a receiver, you should be getting window scaling negotiated during the TCP handshake in the inbound direction. Have you tried downloading something?